# Random walks on randomly evolving graphs

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks, random-graphs

I am interested in analyzing a random walk on a growing tree with vertices labelled on a tree with following properties.

- The number of nodes at depth $k$ is a an exponential function of $k$. One can assume for simplicity that function is $2^k$ is a binary tree is considered. However, I'd like to consider more general possibilities as well.
- Traversal: the random walk starts at the root node, and randomly traverses down each level by randomly choosing a vertex by interpreting the value of a vertex - which is between 0 and 1 - as a probability of transitioning to that vertex. When a leaf node is encountered, the random walk deterministically moves back to the root.
- Tree growth: when the random walk reaches a leaf node, it opens up all possible children of the lead node and assigns values to newly added vertices according to a pre-defined rule.
- Vertex reinforced: the random walk is vertex reinforced in the sense that when the random walk reaches a leaf done, it updates the numerical value of the vertices along the path it took down the tree according to some pre-defined rule.

I would like to analyze the behavior of such random walks. Could someone point me towards references in the literature that analyze such models?